# Svnkit + ssh authentication error (E170001)

Tags: java, svnkit

I am a bit new here but I need some help with my code. Here it is:

```
SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup(); 

    SVNURL url = 
      SVNURL. 
          parseURIEncoded("svn+ssh://xxx"); 
    File keyFile = 
          new File("C://Users/xxxx/Documents/priave_key/private_key.ppk"); 
    System.out.println("PPK file space:"+keyFile.getTotalSpace());
    SVNSSHAuthentication sshCredentials = 
         new SVNSSHAuthentication(Settings.name, keyFile, Settings.pass, 22, false, url, false); 
    System.out.println(sshCredentials.getPrivateKey()==null);
    System.out.println("hasPrivateKey(): "+sshCredentials.hasPrivateKey());
    SVNUserNameAuthentication authorNameCredentials = new SVNUserNameAuthentication(Settings.name, false); 
    SVNPasswordAuthentication passwordCredentials =  new SVNPasswordAuthentication(Settings.name, Settings.pass, false); 

    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = 
        new BasicAuthenticationManager(new SVNAuthentication[] { 
                     sshCredentials, 
                     authorNameCredentials, 
                     passwordCredentials}); 
    SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url); 
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager); 

    try { 

        SVNDirEntry info = repository.info("", -1); 
        System.out.println(info); 
    } finally { 
        repository.closeSession(); 
    }
```

So after running this I get this output:

```
PPK file space:107374178304
false
hasPrivateKey(): true
Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn:     E170001: Authentication required for 'xxx@svn+ssh://xxx'
    at     org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.jav    a:47)
    at     org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.jav    a:41)
    at 

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.BasicAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(BasicAuthentic    ationManager.java:223)
at     org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNSSHConnector.open(SVNSSHConnector.java:141)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.open(SVNConnection.java:77)
at     org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.openConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.j    ava:1252)
at     org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.info(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1195)
    at SVNTestNew.main(SVNTestNew.java:40)
```

I think this can be a problem with `SVNSSHAuthentication` class because it gives null for `getPrivateKey()` and true for `hasPrivateKey(`.) Or is this a wrong idea? Can anyone tell me how can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me your public and private keys are not at proper place.

If you are using Linux machine then,
For private key you have default path :-

```
${USER_HOME}/.ssh/abc.rsa or abc.dsa
```

And you have to Store your public key at server in :

Default Path :-

```
${USER_HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can change your Path in `/etc/sshd_config file`